# Does user have to logoff then back on if I change /etc/sudoers?

Tags: sudo

Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.10 (No we can't upgrade, please don't ask.)

I have a user, 'tina' who is logged into the system. I need her and user 'lu' to use chmod, chgrp, and chown commands for certain reasons (no they don't know enough to be a security risk, we have daily backups anyway). At first I used `sudo nedit /etc/sudoers` to edit the file. Whereon I added this line:

```
tina,lu ALL=/bin/chmod /bin/chown /bin/chgrp
```

Then I found I have to use the `visudo` command, which I did, and I saved the file without edits.

So I went to test her use of `chgrp` and I got an error like "Does not have permission to use this command".

- If I change sudoers do the users need to log off unix shell windows and logon again? The man pages didn't say nor did any pages on Google.
- Do I have to restart the server?

Comment: No you don't need to restart anything. It might be the syntax of your sudo rule, but can you post the full `sudo` command you're running to test? It's also worth noting that giving a user `chown` effectively gives them unrestricted root on the machine. They have to know how to exploit it, but it's not exceptionally difficult to do that. You might make your sudo command spec more specific so that they can only do certain directories.

Comment: Commas are missing in you configuration. It should be :
`tina,lu ALL=/bin/chmod,/bin/chown,/bin/chgrp`. Although it's probably not the right thing to do anyway.

Comment: sudoers is consulted each time, so as long as your syntax is correct, it will work without logout/login (unless the user needs to be in a newly-created group for the rule)

Comment: @Bratchley it's hard to restrict a `sudo` command to part of the filesystem without resorting to something like a script that front-ends `chown`

Comment: @roaima Fair enough given `..` but the point still stands that this is probably not what they want to do because it's not exceptionally difficult to exploit this.

Comment: @Bratchley I agree completely

Answer (score 1):

tina needs to write `sudo chgrp ...`. Otherwise the `sudoers` is not considered.

Comment: I think this answer addresses one possible failure scenario (tina not typing 'sudo' before chgrp -- it wasn't made explicit what tina actually typed), but it does not address the (logical) sudoers syntax "error" listed in the Q that fails to give chgrp access to tina, nor the two explicit questions in the Q about logging off & on and restarting the server.