# RHEL How to login as different user from shell?

Tags: rhel, sudo, login

Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.10 (No we can't upgrade.)

This is related to [my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282041/does-user-have-to-logoff-then-back-on-if-i-change-etc-sudoers). I would like to be able to login as another user, like 'tina', so I can test her sudoer permissions.

- My default shell is csh. (Don't laugh, we don't need anything fancy.)
- I tried `login tina` and that didn't work. I got an error `Not a login shell.`
- I can't use our Xwindows client because her server Xwindows is set up to go to her IP and her IP only. (Client is Hummingbird Exceed 14.0 for me.)
- I didn't see a question just like mine here.
- `telnet` to the same IP address so I can login as another user gives me an error `Connection refused.`

Got any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've used the `sudo -l -U <user>` command to check that sudo has a command set configured for that user...

Comment: @Thomas_N, I just did and she does have access to the commands needed.

Comment: Then @DarkHeart has your most complete answer for testing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see another users sudo permissions you can use: `sudo -l -U <user>`. Provided you have enough permissions yourself.

Or (to answer the question) you can use the `su` command (aka switch-user). Running it as `su - tina` will switch to that user and run the login scripts (drop the `-` to skip this part). You will be prompted for their password.

Or, you use sudo - `sudo -u <user> -i` (-i = simulate initial login). You will be prompted for your password. This only works if you have enough permissions